# Querying has_many through Rails Objects for an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a rails object People, People has many assignments through school_assignments.  Assignments has an attribute 'type', what I want to do is write a function that will return all the people that have a assignment type of "finished" or "started".  I am not sure how to do this or if it is possible any help would be greatly appreciated.  What I have so far is below.

```
   People.where('people.assignments.name = ? or people.assignments.name ?' 'finished', 'started')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
People.joins(school_assignments: :assignments).where(assignments: { type: %w[finished started] })
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, People actually has_many assignments through school_assignments.  Do you know how to do this with the join table.  Because the above is not working with the has_many relationship.

Comment: I've updated my answer to work w/ a `has_many :through`. Please update your question though so that people that come along later won't be confused.

Comment: What about scopes for this case?